# Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, undefined)

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet

I have a issue with my Leaflet map. I'm trying to show all the markers to the map, but it seems that it doesn't want to work on my website, but on the local server(xampp) it's working perfectly..what it's the problem? Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
  function addScoala1() {
   for(var i=0; i<scoala.length; i++) {
    var greenIcon = new L.Icon({
  iconUrl: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png',
  shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12, 41],
  popupAnchor: [1, -34],
  shadowSize: [41, 41]
});
    var marker = L.marker( [scoala[i]['latitudine'], scoala[i]['longitudine']], {icon: greenIcon}).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup( "<b>" + scoala[i]['scoala']+"</b><br>Detalii:" + scoala[i]['detalii'] + "<br />Telefon: " + scoala[i]['telefon']);
   }
  }

function addMuzeu1() {
   for(var i=0; i<muzeu.length; i++) {
    var marker = L.marker( [muzeu[i]['latitudine'], muzeu[i]['longitudine']]).addTo(map);
    marker.bindPopup( "<b>" + muzeu[i]['muzeu']+"</b><br>Detalii:" + muzeu[i]['detalii'] + "<br />Telefon: " + muzeu[i]['telefon']);
   }
  }
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var map = L.map('map').setView([44.9323281,26.0306833], 12,25);

  L.tileLayer( 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWVnYTYzODIiLCJhIjoiY2ozbXpsZHgxMDAzNjJxbndweDQ4am5mZyJ9.uHEjtQhnIuva7f6pAfrdTw', {
   maxZoom: 18,
   attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/"> OpenStreetMap </a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/"> CC-BY-SA </a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
   id: 'examples.map-i875mjb7'
  }).addTo(map);
  var scoala = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($scoala) ?>');
  var muzeu = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($muzeu) ?>');
  console.log(scoala);
 addScoala1();
 addMuzeu1();
});
</script>
```

The variables are:

```
 $scoala = $conn->getScoalaList();
 $muzeu = $conn->getMuzeuList();
 $zona = $conn->getZonaList();
```

And the getScoalaList() and other functions are:

```
 public function getScoalaList()
    {
          $arr = array();
          $statement = $this->aDBConn->prepare( "SELECT id, nume, detalii, latitudine, longitudine, telefon, cuv_cheie from scoala order by nume ASC");
          $statement->bind_result( $id, $scoala1, $detalii1, $latitudine1, $longitudine1, $telefon1, $cuv_cheie1);
          $statement->execute();
          while ($statement->fetch()) {
            $arr = array('id' => $id, 'scoala' => $scoala1, 'detalii' => $detalii1, 'latitudine' => $latitudine1, 'longitudine' => $longitudine1, 'telefon' => $telefon1, 'cuv_cheie' => $cuv_cheie1);
          }
          $statement->close();

          return $arr;
    }
        public function getMuzeuList()
    {
          $arr = array();
          $statement = $this->aDBConn->prepare( "SELECT id, nume, detalii, latitudine, longitudine, telefon, cuv_cheie from muzeu order by nume ASC");
          $statement->bind_result( $id, $muzeu, $detalii, $latitudine1, $longitudine1, $telefon, $cuv_cheie);
          $statement->execute();
          while ($statement->fetch()) {
            $arr =array('id' => $id, 'muzeu' => $muzeu, 'detalii' => $detalii, 'latitudine' => $latitudine1, 'longitudine' => $longitudine1, 'telefon' => $telefon, 'cuv_cheie' => $cuv_cheie);
          }
          $statement->close();

          return $arr;
    }
```

I don't know what can be the problem...any ideas? It could help me a lot.. i'm a noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved the issue, I should add the addScoala1() and other functions to document.ready() function..